# Can we convert PDF file to Word Document?

Tags: apex, renderas

I have a VF page on which I save that VF page content as a PDF, Now there is a new requirement in which I have to save a Word DOC file as well with that PDF so that I can perform some changes on it.

So now what I want to ask is How to convert a pdf file to DOC or Create a new DOC file from the blob of that PDF?

FYI ,I am using renderAs="pdf"  on vf page.
**ContentVersion:**

```
String encodedBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(body);
ContentVersion conVer = new ContentVersion();
conVer.ContentLocation = 'S';
conVer.PathOnClient = quote.Name+'.docx';
conVer.Title = 'Proposal '+ quote.Name;
conVer.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(encodedBlob);
insert conVer;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to convert existing pdf version of the page, I suggest clone the current visualforce page and instead of render as pdf use `contentType="application/msword#filename.doc`

Now you can read this content as blob in apex

Comment: Thank u for the quick response @mohith, I tried the solution suggested but the VF page is saving as PDF as previously.  Maybe something is wrong with contentVersion that I am inserting.
Here I am using it as :
In updated question

Comment: PageReference pdfPage = Page.CRcontract; Blob pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContent(); I would try getting the getContent via pagereference

Comment: And make sure page names is correct

Comment: Thank for the help, one last issue I am facing is that I am not able to get the images in the doc file which I am accessing from static resources.

Comment: I think it’s a different question! And it will need you to share code.

Comment: oh, ok I'll create a new question for this.